# grep of 50000 strings in a big file performance improvement

Tags: performance, shell, unix

I have a file, which is about 200 MB of size, with about 1.2 M lines in it. Let's say it as reading.txt. I have another file, input.txt,
in which there are about 50000 lines. I want to take a string in each line from input.txt file and grep in reading.txt. For a matched line,
in reading.txt get that complete line and write into other file, output.txt.
As of now, I am looping through every string of input.txt file, grep in reading.txt file. This approach is consuming more than 1 hour time.
Is there any option to increase performance so that time consumption reduces for this process.

```
    while read line
    do
            LC_ALL=C grep ${line} reading.txt 2>/dev/null
    done<input.txt >> output.txt
```

Comment: `while read line; do ... done < bigfile` is a performance disaster.  `read` does a system call for every single byte of input.  If performance is a concern, that is (almost certainly) the main culprit.

Comment: Please use the internationally agreed symbol `MB` for megabyte https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Megabyte If you use `mb` it looks like *"millibits"*.

Answer (score 2):

`man grep` yields (among others):

```
       -f FILE, --file=FILE
              Obtain patterns from FILE, one per line.  If this option is used
              multiple times or is combined with  the  -e  (--regexp)  option,
              search  for  all  patterns  given.  The empty file contains zero
              patterns, and therefore matches nothing.
```

Answer (score 0):

```
grep -f input.txt reading.txt > output.txt
```

...will print all lines in 'reading.txt', with a sub string matching a line in 'input.txt', in the *order* of 'reading.txt', to 'output.txt'

You don't specify this, but it may be relevant (you said 1.2MB lines in 'reading.txt') - a separate output file for every matching line:

```
#!/bin/sh

nl='
'
IFS=$nl

c=0
for i in $(grep -f input.txt reading.txt); do
        c=$((c+1))
        echo "$i" > output$c.txt
done
```

There *are* tidier methods of setting IFS to a new line, for example in `bash`: `IFS=$'\n'` (also you can use `> output$((++c)).txt` in bash)